# Vim, insert text from register on beginning of row

Tags: vim

Is there a way to tell (g)Vim to insert from register at the beginning of a row? I know I can use s/^/[text]/ but I was thinking more along the lines of :g/[text]/ "+p except that that doesn't work. I guess the problem is that there's no way for Vim to decide where to put the content of the register.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
:g/pattern/s/^/\=@a/
```

will insert the contents of register `a` at the start of every line containing `pattern`. See

```
:help sub-replace-expression
:help expr-register
```

Comment: `:%s/^\zs.*pattern/\=@a/` will also do it.

Comment: @Luc, I'm pretty sure you mean \ze

Answer (score 0):

You can use `P` to paste *before* cursor (and `p` to paste after).

So if you got at the beginning of a row with `0` or `^`, you can they use `"+P`.